# Using non serialisable objects in python beam functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-beam

According to beam's documentation:

> Transient fields in your function object are not transmitted to worker
>   instances, because they are not automatically serialized.

My code:

```
class myBeamFunction(beam.DoFn):

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state
        self.my_nonserialisable_object = new Nonserialisable_object()

    def process(self, element):
        return self.my_nonserialisable_object.do(element)
```

My application failed because:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

From the stacktrace, I saw it was caused by:

```
Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py
```

I wonder is there a way that I can init all of non-serialisable variables I need for my function at the worker instances?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with DoFn.StartBundle method. @[Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html).

> Initialize the state in each DoFn instance, in a DoFn.StartBundle
>   method. This is good if the initialization doesn't depend on any
>   information known only by the main program or computed by earlier
>   pipeline operations, but is the same for all instances of this DoFn
>   for all program executions, say setting up empty caches or
>   initializing constant data.

It happens to be the same in python. So with a bit of modification:

```
class myBeamFunction(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_nonserialisable_object = None

    def start_bundle(self, context=None):
         self.my_nonserialisable_object = new Nonserialisable_object()

    def process(self, element):
        return self.my_nonserialisable_object.do(element)
```